# Splitting a string and insert into a database

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I've setup a SqlServer Express and created the tables i need. Here's however where I run into a problem.

I have this textfile containing lot's of different info, here's and example:

```
Line1: 00001, Some name, Address, Email
Line2: 00002..
```

How do I split lines, which are all divided with commas between the relevant information and move the information into the correct columns in my database?

```
ID      | Name        | Address      | Email    |   <-- Columns

000001  | Some name   | Some street  | @mail    |   <-- Data inserted

000002 etc.
```

I hope you understand my question, I did my best to visualize it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a one-time insert (manually import it via SQL) or an on-going set of files that will be received (programmatic solution)

Comment: Are you using SQL 2008?  If you are I might be able to provide a better solution, we can turn your CSV into a virtual table in C# and pass it to a stored procedure as a table which you can insert from.  If you are only doing this once though a bulk insert such as @Atnhonyvscode suggested is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Import-CSV-File-Into-SQL-Server-Using-Bulk-Insert.aspx

```
BULK INSERT Contact
FROM 'c:\TestData.csv'  -- Full path of the Delimited file
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'   --Use to shift the control to next row
)
```

or if you're just after a once off import right click your db in management studio -> tasks -> import data, choose flat file source and follow the wizard

Comment: I forgot to specify that it's .txt file

Comment: doesnt matter - its just a delimited file to SQL server, just point it at the .txt file and it'll work